# Error 410 gone after moving from local server to live

Tags: php, server, http-status-code-410

I have created a site and everything is working fine locally in WAMP, however, I moved everything to my shared hosting account and am getting a 410 error:

```
Gone
The requested resource
/admin/product_edit_parse.php
is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address. Please remove all references to this resource.

Additionally, a 410 Gone error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I moved all files and everything else seems to be working so far except for this one file. This file is not actually viewable anywhere it is on the admin side of my site for editing products. My site sends a HTTP request to this page and gets a response via AJAX like so:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", query_string, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I can only see the 410 error in the console when nothing happens.

If I go directly to the pages URL with the query string attached (`admin/product_edit_parse.php?foo=bar&bar=foo`) it gives me the same error.

However, if I go to the URL with out the query string I get a time out error:

```
This site can’t be reached
************** took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

### Edit

This is how I'm building my query string

```
$("#product_edit_submit").on("click", function(){
    var product_id = $("#product_id").val();
    var product_name = $("#product_name").val();
    var product_sort = $("#product_sort").val();
    var product_category = $("#product_category").val();
    var product_attribute = $("#product_attribute").val();
    var product_description = richTextField.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
    product_description = product_description.replace(/&quot;/g,"");
    product_description = product_description.replace(/&nbsp;/g,"");
    var product_supplier = $("#product_supplier").val();
    var product_model_no = $("#product_model_no").val();
    var product_cost = $("#product_cost").val();
    var product_meta = $("#product_meta").val();
    var spec_1 = $("#spec_1").val();
    var spec_2 = $("#spec_2").val();
    var spec_3 = $("#spec_3").val();
    var spec_4 = $("#spec_4").val();
    var spec_5 = $("#spec_5").val();
    var spec_6 = $("#spec_6").val();
    var spec_7 = $("#spec_7").val();
    var spec_8 = $("#spec_8").val();
    var spec_9 = $("#spec_9").val();
    var spec_10 = $("#spec_10").val();
    var spec_11 = $("#spec_11").val();
    var spec_12 = $("#spec_12").val();
    var spec_13 = $("#spec_13").val();
    var spec_14 = $("#spec_14").val();
    var spec_15 = $("#spec_15").val();
    
    var value_1 = $("#value_1").val();
    var value_2 = $("#value_2").val();
    var value_3 = $("#value_3").val();
    var value_4 = $("#value_4").val();
    var value_5 = $("#value_5").val();
    var value_6 = $("#value_6").val();
    var value_7 = $("#value_7").val();
    var value_8 = $("#value_8").val();
    var value_9 = $("#value_9").val();
    var value_10 = $("#value_10").val();
    var value_11 = $("#value_11").val();
    var value_12 = $("#value_12").val();
    var value_13 = $("#value_13").val();
    var value_14 = $("#value_14").val();
    var value_15 = $("#value_15").val();
    
    var pricing = [];
    for (i = 0; i <15; i++) {
        var checkbox = "checkbox"+i;
        if ($("#"+checkbox).is(':checked')) {
            for (j = 1; j <=2; j++) {
                var priceValue = 'priceValue'+i+'_'+j;
                var priceCurrency = 'priceCurrency'+i+'_'+j;
                var priceAttribute = 'priceAttribute'+i+'_'+j;
                var value = $('#'+priceValue).val();
                var currency = $('#'+priceCurrency).val();
                var attribute = $('#'+priceAttribute).val();
                var item = [];
                item.push(value);
                item.push(currency);
                item.push(attribute);
                pricing.push('item'+item);
            }
        }
    }
            
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("product_image_1", document.getElementById("product_image_1").files[0]);
    formData.append("product_image_2", document.getElementById("product_image_2").files[0]);
    formData.append("product_image_3", document.getElementById("product_image_3").files[0]);
    formData.append("product_image_4", document.getElementById("product_image_4").files[0]);
    formData.append("product_image_5", document.getElementById("product_image_5").files[0]);
            
    var query_string = "product_edit_parse.php?";
    query_string += "id="+encodeURIComponent(product_id);
    query_string += "&name="+encodeURIComponent(product_name);
    query_string += "&sort="+encodeURIComponent(product_sort);
    query_string += "&cat="+encodeURIComponent(product_category);
    query_string += "&att="+encodeURIComponent(product_attribute);
    query_string += "&desc="+encodeURIComponent(product_description);
    query_string += "&supp="+encodeURIComponent(product_supplier);
    query_string += "&mono="+encodeURIComponent(product_model_no);
    query_string += "&cost="+encodeURIComponent(product_cost);
    query_string += "&meta="+encodeURIComponent(product_meta);
    
    query_string += "&spec_1="+spec_1;
    query_string += "&spec_2="+spec_2;
    query_string += "&spec_3="+spec_3;
    query_string += "&spec_4="+spec_4;
    query_string += "&spec_5="+spec_5;
    query_string += "&spec_6="+spec_6;
    query_string += "&spec_7="+spec_7;
    query_string += "&spec_8="+spec_8;
    query_string += "&spec_9="+spec_9;
    query_string += "&spec_10="+spec_10;
    query_string += "&spec_11="+spec_11;
    query_string += "&spec_12="+spec_12;
    query_string += "&spec_13="+spec_13;
    query_string += "&spec_14="+spec_14;
    query_string += "&spec_15="+spec_15;
    
    query_string += "&value_1="+value_1;
    query_string += "&value_2="+value_2;
    query_string += "&value_3="+value_3;
    query_string += "&value_4="+value_4;
    query_string += "&value_5="+value_5;
    query_string += "&value_6="+value_6;
    query_string += "&value_7="+value_7;
    query_string += "&value_8="+value_8;
    query_string += "&value_9="+value_9;
    query_string += "&value_10="+value_10;
    query_string += "&value_11="+value_11;
    query_string += "&value_12="+value_12;
    query_string += "&value_13="+value_13;
    query_string += "&value_14="+value_14;
    query_string += "&value_15="+value_15;
        
    query_string += "&price_array="+pricing;
    console.log(query_string);
        
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", query_string, true);
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
});
```

`console.log(query_string);` returns:

```
product_edit_parse.php?id=1&name=TPM%200.1-Lifting%20Magnet%20100kg&sort=1&cat=1&att=1&desc=%0A%09%09%20%3Cp%3ETPM%200.1%20Permanent%20Lifting%20Magnet%20Capacity%3A%20100kg%3C%2Fp%3E%20%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%20xml%3D%22space%22%3E%3C!--%20p.p1%20%7Bmargin%3A%200.0px%200.0px%200.0px%200.0px%3B%20font%3A%208.0px%20Times%7D%20p.p2%20%7Bmargin%3A%200.0px%200.0px%200.0px%200.0px%3B%20font%3A%2010.0px%20Times%7D%20--%3E%3C%2Fstyle%3E%20%3Cp%3ETPM%20permanent%20lifting%20magnets%20are%20ideal%20tools%20for%20easy%2C%20quick%20and%20economical%20transport%20of%20heavy%20objects%20made%20from%20ferro-magnetic%20material.%20Typical%20operating%20areas%20are%20workshops%20and%20warehouses%2Cloading%20and%20unloading%20of%20machines%20as%20well%20as%20construction%20of%20jigs%20and%20fixtures.%3C%2Fp%3E%20%3Cp%3E%3Cspan%20class%3D%22Apple-converted-space%22%3E%3C%2Fspan%3EFactors%20that%20reduce%20the%20magnetic%20clamping%20force%3A%3C%2Fp%3E%20%3Cp%3EAir%20gap%3A%20High%20magnetic%20forces%20created%20by%20the%20TPM%20allow%20the%20magnet%20to%20clamp%20components%20through%20the%20air%20gap%2C%20however%2C%20air%20gaps%20will%20reduce%20the%20magnetic%20performance%20as%20they%20provide%20a%20barrier%20between%20the%20contact%20surfaces.%20Air%20gaps%20occur%20in%20a%20number%20of%20different%20ways%20such%20as%20paint%2C%20dust%20and%20heavy%20mill%20scale.%20Poorly%20machined%20surfaces%20also%20constitute%20an%20air%20gap.%20Please%20down%20rate%20the%20magnet%20capacity%20in%20accordance%20with%20the%20adhesive%20force%2Fair%20gap%20diagram%20below.%3C%2Fp%3E%20%3Cp%3EMaterial%20thickness%3A%20If%20the%20TPM%20is%20used%20to%20lift%20plates%20thinner%20than%20the%20recommended%20minimum%20thickness%2C%20the%20clamping%20forces%20will%20be%20significantly%20reduced.%20Performance%20curves%20can%20be%20identified%20in%20conjunction%20with%20the%20adhesive%20force%2Fflat%20thickness%20diagram%20below%3A%3C%2Fp%3E%20%3Cp%3EContact%20area%3A%20Full%20lifting%20capacity%20can%20only%20be%20achieved%20when%20the%20magnet%20has%20full%20contact%20area%20with%20the%20component%20being%20lifted.%20If%20the%20contact%20surface%20has%20holes%20in%20or%20is%20uneven%20then%20the%20performance%20will%20be%20affected%20accordingly.%20Always%20carry%20out%20a%20trial%20lift%20in%20these%20circumstances%20to%20establish%20correct%20lifting%20before%20transporting%20the%20load.%3C%2Fp%3E%20%3Cp%3EMaterial%20type%3A%20Certain%20materials%20have%20different%20abilities%20to%20carry%20magnetism.%20For%20materials%20other%20than%20mild%20steel%20a%20reduction%20factor%20must%20be%20applied%20in%20order%20to%20calculate%20the%20effective%20clamping%20force.%3C%2Fp%3E%20%3Cp%3ETypical%20values%3A%3C%2Fp%3E%20%3Cp%3EFerrous%20alloy%20steels%200.8%3C%2Fp%3E%20%3Cp%3EHigh%20carbon%20steels%200.7%3C%2Fp%3E%20%3Cp%3ECast%20iron%200.55%3C%2Fp%3E%20%3Cp%3EExamples%20of%20reduced%20WLL%3A%3C%2Fp%3E%20%3Cp%3EMild%20steel%20500g%3C%2Fp%3E%20%3Cp%3ECast%20iron%20500kg%20x%200.55%20%3D%20275kgs%3C%2Fp%3E%0A&supp=&mono=&cost=&meta=&spec_1=&spec_2=&spec_3=&spec_4=&spec_5=&spec_6=&spec_7=&spec_8=&spec_9=&spec_10=&spec_11=&spec_12=&spec_13=&spec_14=&spec_15=&value_1=&value_2=&value_3=&value_4=&value_5=&value_6=&value_7=&value_8=&value_9=&value_10=&value_11=&value_12=&value_13=&value_14=&value_15=&price_array=
```

Comment: This may have just been the fore-runner of the entire server going down... Can no longer access domains cpanel, can't connect via FTP, all resources on domain are now timing out.... Gotta love friday mornings...

Comment: please show us what is on  `query_string`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your comment. I do not think this is an issue now. Just off the phone to my hosting company think it's an issue on their side. (makes a change, I usually just expect there to be issues with my code :P)

Comment: Ha :) Dont we all

Comment: ok so I'm still not sure what is going on with this after further testing our server seems to be down on multiple browsers, multiple devices, multiple networks etc,. ......and then it randomly works on another device and the hosting company can't reproduce it either

Comment: Did you create a Virtual Host on WAMPServer to test this code in, or did you just put this project in a subfolder of `/wamp/www/`

Comment: I ask because the leading backslash on this `/admin/product_edit_parse.php` may be causing you issues

Comment: Hi no virtual host, just basic straight outta the box wamp installation, that backslash is only in the error message. I'm building my query string like in the edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the shared domain host doing checks for malicious files. Still no straight answer from them about why this was being marked as malicious.

Comment: I am also using cpanel and I am having the same problems. how did you manage to solve the issue within cpanel? thanks